# If $E[Y\vert \mathcal{G}]=X$ and $E[X^2]=E[Y^2]<\infty$ then $X=Y$ a.s.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value

Let $X,Y$ be random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and $\mathcal{G}\subseteq \mathcal{F}$ a $\sigma-$field

If $E[Y\vert \mathcal{G}]=X$ and $E[X^2]=E[Y^2]<\infty$ then show $X=Y$ a.s.

I don't know where to start so I guess I will define the event $A:=\{X\neq Y\}$ from $E[Y\vert \mathcal{G}]=X$, I know that for $B \in \mathcal{G}: \int_{B}YdP=\int_{B}XdP$

and then somehow I need to show that $\int_{B\cap A}YdP=\int_{B\cap A}XdP=0$

I do not know how $E[X^2]=E[Y^2]$ is supposed to help me

Comment: Can you do the simplest special case:  If $\mathbb E[Y] = a$ and $\mathbb E[Y^2] = a^2$, then $Y=a$ a.s.  Here we took $\mathcal G = \mathcal F$ so that $X = a$ is a constant.

Comment: In addition to the GEdgar comment: If  $E[Y|\mathcal{G}]=X$ then you know $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. You can compute $E[(Y-X)^2|\mathcal{G}]$.

Comment: For the sake of intuition: The conditional expectation results in an *orthogonal* decomposition $Y=X+(Y-X)$ in $L^2$, in that $E[X(Y-X)]=0$. Because of this orthogonality, if $X$ has the same length as $Y$, then the perpendicular component $Y-X$ must have length $0$, and $X$ must equal $Y$ a.s.

Comment: @JohnDawkins I get to $E[(X-Y)^{2}\vert \mathcal{G}]= E[Y^2\vert \mathcal{G}]-X^2$. But how can I use the Tower Property to show that $E[(X-Y)^2]=E[Y^2]- E[X^2]$ ?

Comment: Just take expectations of both sides of your conditional expectation identity.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the proof is to show that $E(X-Y)^2=0$ from which it would follow that $X=Y$ a.s. (In general if $Z\geq 0$ w.p.1 and $EZ=0$, then $Z=0$ w.p.1)

To this end we will use the tower law and compute 
$$
\begin{align}
E[(X-Y)^2\mid \mathcal{G}]&=E[X^2-2XY+Y^2\mid \mathcal{G}]\\
&=E(X^2\mid \mathcal{G})-2E(XY\mid \mathcal{G})+E(Y^2\mid \mathcal{G})\tag{0}\\
&=X^2-2XE(Y\mid \mathcal{G})+E(Y^2\mid \mathcal{G})\tag{1}\\
&=E(Y^2\mid \mathcal{G})-X^2
\end{align}
$$
where in (0) we use linearity and in (1) we use the fact that $X=E(Y\mid \mathcal{G})$ whence $X\in \mathcal{G}$ and use the pullout property.

The tower law implies that
$$
E(X-Y)^2=EY^2-EX^2=0
$$
as desired.

Comment: Minor issue: You write "$X \in \mathcal{G}$" but that is not quite precise because $X$ is a random variable, not a set in $\mathcal{G}$.  I believe you mean $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable as in my prior comment, for use in the "pull out what is known" property.

Comment: Why does the tower law imply that $E(X-Y)^{2}=EY^{2}-EX^{2}$? Do we set $\mathcal{G}= \{ \varnothing, \Omega\}$, but surely this is not the tower property